# What should the kendo grid filter object look like when multiple filters (using and + or) are applied?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid, and two html multi select drop down lists.  Each drop down list filters a different column in the grid.  I can successfully filter the grid when only 1 value is selected from either one or both drop downs.  However, as soon as I select a second value from either drop down, I have a problem.  I get the error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "

"and" logic should be applied for filters from different columns/drop downs.  For example, I have a column for LocationID, and another for DepartmentID.  If I select a location from the location drop down, and a department from the dept drop down, the grid should be filtered such that LocationID = selected AND DepartmentID = selected.  This part works, and the filter object is structured as follows in this case:

[image: single selections]

However, when 2 locations are selected, the grid should show results where (LocationID = selected1 OR LocationID=selected2) AND DepartmentID = selected.  This part does not work, and my main question is what the filter object should look like in this case.

Here is my jquery:

```
//filter based on drop downs
        $("#LocationList,#DepartmentList").change(function () {
            var dropdownValue = $(this).val();

            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            if (id == "DepartmentList") {
                applyFilter("DepartmentID", $(this).val());
            } else {
                applyFilter("LocationID", $(this).val());
            }

        });

function applyFilter(filterField, filterValue) {
            var gridData = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
            var currFilterObj = gridData.dataSource.filter();
            var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];

            if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
                    if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
                        currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //the problem is below, with how I'm building the filter.
            if (filterValue != "" && filterValue != null) {
                var mainFilter = { logic: "", filters: currentFilters };
                if (filterValue.length > 1) {
                    mainFilter.logic = "or";
                    $.each(filterValue, function (key, value) {
                        mainFilter.filters.push({ field: filterField, operator: "eq", value: value });
                    })
                }
                else {
                    mainFilter.logic = "and";
                    mainFilter.filters.push({ field: filterField, operator: "eq", value: filterValue})
                }
                console.log(mainFilter);
                gridData.dataSource.filter(mainFilter);
            } else if (currentFilters.length == 0) {
                //clear filter
                gridData.dataSource.filter({});
            } else {
                //just apply currentFilters
                gridData.dataSource.filter({ logic: "and", filters: currentFilters });
            }
        }
```

mainFilter with multiple selections from Location drop down:
[image: multiselect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by enabling the native kendo column filters and logging the filter object structure when filtering multiple values from multiple columns.  I then re-worked my applyFilter function so that it produced filters in the correct format/structure.  Here's the result of using the native filters on two different columns:

[image: native]

I have two columns I'm filtering, so I broke the process down to build each filter separately, and then add to the grid's filter object.

Here's the updated & working function:

```
function applyFilter(filterField, filterValue) {
            var gridData = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
            var currFilterObj = gridData.dataSource.filter();

            var currentFilters = currFilterObj ? currFilterObj.filters : [];
            //remove existing filter for this field
            if (currentFilters && currentFilters.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < currentFilters.length; i++) {
                    if (currentFilters[i].field == filterField) {
                        currentFilters.splice(i, 1);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            var locationfilter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
            var departmentfilter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
            var bigKahunafilter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
            //add remaining filters to appropriate category
            if (currentFilters.field == "LocationID") {
                locationfilter.filters.push(currentFilters);
            } else if (currentFilters.field == "DepartmentID") {
                departmentfilter.filters.push(currentFilters);
            }

            //the problem is below, with how I'm building the filter.
            if (filterValue != "" && filterValue != null) {
                if (filterField == "LocationID") {
                    if (filterValue.length > 1) {
                        locationfilter.logic = "or";
                    }
                    $.each(filterValue, function (key, value) {
                        locationfilter.filters.push({ field: filterField, operator: "eq", value: parseInt(value) });
                    })
                } else if (filterField == "DepartmentID") {
                    if (filterValue.length > 1) {
                        departmentfilter.logic = "or";
                    }
                    $.each(filterValue, function (key, value) {
                    departmentfilter.filters.push({ field: filterField, operator: "eq", value: parseInt(value) });
                    })
                }

                if (locationfilter.filters.length > 0) {
                    bigKahunafilter.filters.push(locationfilter);
                }
                if (departmentfilter.filters.length > 0) {
                    bigKahunafilter.filters.push(departmentfilter);
                }

                gridData.dataSource.filter(bigKahunafilter);
            } else if (currentFilters.length == 0) {
                //clear filter
                gridData.dataSource.filter({});
            } else {
                //just apply currentFilters
                gridData.dataSource.filter({ logic: "and", filters: currentFilters });
            }
        }
```